# Conditional Probability for open roads between towns

Tags: statistics, probability

There are 2 roads from A to B, and 3 roads from B to C. Each road is blocked
by snow with probability 0.15, and the blocking events of all 5 roads are jointly independent.

(a) Calculate the probability that there is an open road from A to B, given that there is
no open road from A to C.

(b) Now there is a new road directly from A to C. The road is blocked by snow with
probability 0.25, and again the blocking events of all roads are jointly independent. Calculate
the probability that there is an open road from A to B, given that there is no open road from
A to C.

This question requires some usage of Bayes Theorem

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! Take a [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour). Have a look at the [guidelines](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: In particular: What have you tried?

Comment: @DominikS: The blocking events from $A$ to $B$ and from $B$ to $C$ are all independent; that doesn't imply that the blocking events from $A$ to $B$ are independent from the one from $A$ to $C$.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks, it seems I haven't read the post carefully enough.

Answer (score 1):

Let $XY$ denote the event that there’s no open road from $X$ to $Y$. Then $\mathsf P(AB)=0.15^2=0.0225$ and $\mathsf P(BC)=0.15^3=0.003375$.

The conditional probability for (a) is

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathsf P\left(\overline{AB}\mid AC\right)
&=&
\mathsf P\left(\overline{AB}\mid AB\cup BC\right)
\\
&=&\frac{\mathsf P\left(\overline{AB}\cap(AB\cup BC)\right)}{\mathsf P(AB\cup BC)}
\\
&=&
\frac{\mathsf P\left(\overline{AB}\cap BC\right)}{1-\mathsf P\left(\overline{AB}\cap\overline{BC}\right)}
\\
&=&
\frac{\left(1-0.15^2\right)\cdot0.15^3}{1-\left(1-0.15^2\right)\left(1-0.15^3\right)}
\\
&=&
\frac{1173}{9173}
\\
&\approx&
12.8\%\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

That makes sense – it’s so unlikely that all three roads from $B$ to $C$ are blocked that there being no open road from $A$ to $C$ makes it very likely that both roads from $A$ to $B$ are blocked.

Part (b) is badly phrased, in that it asks you to “calculate” but the point of the exercise is actually that you don’t have to calculate. That there’s no open road from $A$ to $C$ implies that the new road is blocked, and since that event is independent of all other events, that means the road might as well not have been there in the first place, so the probability is the same as in (a).